# Include column which is part of clustered index to non-clustered indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a composite clustered index on 2 columns: `OrganizationId`, `SalesOrderId`.

I have 4 foreign keys for which I created 4 non-clustered indexes (each non-clustered index contains 1 column). The 4 columns are not `OrganizationId` and `SalesOrderId`.

I was wondering if I should modify all non-clustered indexes to include the `OrganizationId` as well since it will be used alongside those columns.

**UPDATE:** This is the model (I use *EF Core 3.1, Code-First, Fluent API*):

```cs
public class SalesOrderLine
{
public int LineId { get; set; } // PK
// Other columns...

// Relationships
public int SalesOrderId { get; set; }
public int SalesOrderRevisionId { get; set; }
public int? ProductId { get; set; }
public Product Product { get; set; }
public int? Tax { get; set; } // don't need an index on this
public int? ShippingMethod { get; set; } // don't need an index on this
public int? ShippingAddressId { get; set; } // don't need an index on this
public CustomerAddress CustomerAddress { get; set; }
public int? JobId { get; set; }
public Job Job { get; set; }
public int? JobLineId { get; set; }
public JobLine JobLine { get; set; }
public int OrganizationId { get; set; }
public List<SalesOrderLineCosting> CostingItems { get; set; }
}
```

This is code from the migration:

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
// Skipped some code...
// Removed some indexes which were not needed (Tax, ShippingMethod, ShippingAddressId)
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_SalesOrderLines_JobId",
    table: "SalesOrderLines",
    column: "JobId",
    unique: true,
    filter: "[JobId] IS NOT NULL");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_SalesOrderLines_JobLineId",
    table: "SalesOrderLines",
    column: "JobLineId",
    unique: true,
    filter: "[JobLineId] IS NOT NULL");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_SalesOrderLines_ProductId",
    table: "SalesOrderLines",
    column: "ProductId",
    unique: true,
    filter: "[ProductId] IS NOT NULL");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_SalesOrderLines_SalesOrderId",
    table: "SalesOrderLines",
    column: "SalesOrderId");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_SalesOrderLines_SalesOrderRevisionId",
    table: "SalesOrderLines",
    column: "SalesOrderRevisionId");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_SalesOrderLines_OrganizationId_SalesOrderId",
    table: "SalesOrderLines",
    columns: new[] { "OrganizationId", "SalesOrderId" })
    .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", true);
}
```

The FKs will be used with the `OrganizationId` most of the time. We always filter by `OrganizationId` first.

Comment: In SQL Server the columns of a clustered index *are included* in all non-clustered indexes on that table; When SQL Server finds rows in a non-clustered index and your query requires columns not included in the index they're used for a key-lookup to seek directly into the clustered index. So no modification is necessary.

Comment: Non-clustered indexes implicitly include the clustered index. As you want to query the column the *first* column your clustered index is ordered on, then `INCLUDE`ing it is unlikely to be beneficial; though you could likely easily test this either in your development environment or a sandbox environment.

Comment: If, however, you were filtering.on the value of `SalesOrderId`, and you had a lot of repeating values in your other columns, then there *may* be a benefit to adding `SalesOrderId` to the `INDEX` (not the `INCLUDE`), but again, testing would give you the real answer.

Comment: Specifically. If the non clustered index is create as `UNIQUE` then the clustered index key column(s) are treated as `INCLUDE`-d columns if not already added explicitly. And if the non clustered index is not created as `UNIQUE` then the clustered index key column(s)  are included in the non clustered index key

Comment: @MartinSmith and also assume this would mean if the clustered index was not created unque then the 4-byte uniquifier managed by SQL Server would also be included in the non-clustered index

Comment: @Stu - yes it would. Hence `3` here `CREATE TABLE T1 (A INT INDEX IX CLUSTERED,B INT INDEX IX_B NONCLUSTERED);SELECT keycnt FROM sysindexes WHERE id = object_id('T1') AND indid = 2`

Comment: or a better way of seeing this https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhJR3.png

Comment: Please show the current table definition with indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use EF but the code posted looks reasonably self explanatory and that you should end up with a table something like this

```
CREATE TABLE SalesOrderLines(
LineId INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_SalesOrderLines PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
OrganizationId INT NOT NULL,
SalesOrderId INT NOT NULL INDEX IX_SalesOrderLines_SalesOrderId,
SalesOrderRevisionId INT NOT NULL INDEX IX_SalesOrderLines_SalesOrderRevisionId,
JobId INT NULL INDEX IX_SalesOrderLines_JobId UNIQUE WHERE [JobId] IS NOT NULL,
JobLineId INT NULL INDEX IX_SalesOrderLines_JobLineId UNIQUE WHERE [JobLineId] IS NOT NULL,
ProductId INT NULL INDEX IX_SalesOrderLines_ProductId UNIQUE WHERE [ProductId] IS NOT NULL,
INDEX IX_SalesOrderLines_OrganizationId_SalesOrderId CLUSTERED (OrganizationId, SalesOrderId)
)
```

I see that you have no `unique` annotation on the clustered index in your code so I assume it is not created as unique in the database either.

This means that any duplicate values for `OrganizationId, SalesOrderId` will get a hidden `UNIQUIFIER` column added and the full clustered index key is `OrganizationId, SalesOrderId,UNIQUIFIER`.

You have four unique nonclustered indexes

- IX_SalesOrderLines_JobId
- IX_SalesOrderLines_ProductId
- IX_SalesOrderLines_JobLineId
- PK_SalesOrderLines

For each of these the three clustered index key columns are added implicitly to the index as `INCLUDE`-d columns. So there is no need to add them explicitly as included columns (and they should not be added as key columns as this would change the uniqueness semantics)

You have two non unique nonclustered indexes

- IX_SalesOrderLines_SalesOrderRevisionId - the entire clustered index key is appended to the key after `SalesOrderRevisionId` - so the full key is `SalesOrderRevisionId ASC, OrganizationId ASC, SalesOrderId ASC, UNIQUIFIER ASC` - If you wanted greater control over either the order of the implicitly added CI keys or the sort direction then you might add these explicitly.
- IX_SalesOrderLines_SalesOrderId - the remaining clustered index key columns are appended to the key after `SalesOrderId` - so the full key is `SalesOrderId ASC, OrganizationId ASC, UNIQUIFIER ASC` - If you wanted greater control over the sort direction of `OrganizationId` you might add it explictly.

In order to see these implicitly added columns you can use `DBCC PAGE`

```
--Add a couple of rows to the table
INSERT SalesOrderLines(LineId, OrganizationId, SalesOrderId, SalesOrderRevisionId, JobId, JobLineId, ProductId)
SELECT LineId = 1, OrganizationId = 100, SalesOrderId = 200, SalesOrderRevisionId = 300, JobId = 400, JobLineId = 500, ProductId = 600 UNION ALL
SELECT LineId = 2, OrganizationId = 100, SalesOrderId = 200, SalesOrderRevisionId = 301, JobId = 401, JobLineId = 501, ProductId = 601

SELECT i.name, 
       CommandToRun = CONCAT('DBCC PAGE(', database_id, ',', allocated_page_file_id, ',', allocated_page_page_id, ',3)')
FROM sys.indexes i
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(db_id(), object_id('SalesOrderLines'), i.index_id, NULL, 'DETAILED') pa
WHERE i.object_id = object_id('SalesOrderLines') AND pa.page_type_desc = 'INDEX_PAGE'
```

Running the command corresponding to the single index page for `IX_SalesOrderLines_SalesOrderRevisionId` returns something like the below (The `(key)` annotation allows you to see this is part of the key rather than just included)

| FileId | PageId | Row | Level | SalesOrderRevisionId (key) | OrganizationId (key) | SalesOrderId (key) | UNIQUIFIER (key) | KeyHashValue | Row Size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 8 | 0 | 0 | 300 | 100 | 200 | 0 | (42c9c288d74b) | 16 |
| 6 | 8 | 1 | 0 | 301 | 100 | 200 | 1 | (6f53ca5cce6d) | 24 |